# Can't fetch data through the key (Firestore)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I can't fetch the data through Firestore key.

[image]

> TypeError: relativePath.split is not a function

```
export const itemsFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(19910929).get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('snapshot:', snapshot);
      })
  };
};
```

Answer (score 10):

I have updated data to that with string.

`19910929` to `'19910929'`

That would work!